# Leetcode 112. Path Sum wrong answer for testcases

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, struct, binary-tree

I am working on Leet code problem [112. Path Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree and an integer `targetSum`, return `true` if the tree has a **root-to-leaf** path such that adding up all the values along the path equals `targetSum`.
>
> A **leaf** is a node with no children.

When executing my code with this test:

```
[2,0]
targetSum = 0
```

...the result is true, but the expected result is false.

It seems to run via `root->left`, and when the final `targetSum != Sum`, it will run a recursion, it will run to `root->NULL`, and the result should be 0. But the result I get is not what I expected...

I don't know how to modify this program?

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *   
 *     struct TreeNode *left;
 *     struct TreeNode *right;
 * };
 */

bool checkhasPath(struct TreeNode* root,int targetSum,int sum){
    sum += root->val;
    count++;
   
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
    if((sum == targetSum) && (!root->left && !root->right)) return 1;
        
    bool res1, res2;
    if(root->left)
        res1 = checkhasPath(root->left,targetSum,sum);
    if(root->right)
        res2 = checkhasPath(root->right,targetSum,sum);
    return res1 || res2;
}

bool hasPathSum(struct TreeNode* root, int targetSum){   
    return checkhasPath(root,targetSum,0);
}
```

Comment: You take `root->val` before testing if root is NULL

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Also, compile with warnings enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- `res1` and `res2` are uninitialised. When the `if` conditions are false, they don't get a value other than the undefined value they started with.
- The check `root == NULL` should be done *before* evaluating `root->val`.

So:

```
bool checkhasPath(struct TreeNode* root,int targetSum,int sum){
    if(root == NULL) return 0; // do this first
    
    sum += root->val;

    if((sum == targetSum) && (!root->left && !root->right)) return 1;
    
    bool res1 = 0, res2 = 0;  // initialise
    if(root->left)
        res1 = checkhasPath(root->left,targetSum,sum);
    if(root->right)
        res2 = checkhasPath(root->right,targetSum,sum);
    
    return res1 || res2;
}
```